# onAudioFocusChange not getting called

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-audiomanager

I am creating a application where a song is played by streaming. My app will continue  to play  when move to background which is OK. But when some other application like a music player of device or may be when I am playing video from youtube at that time both the media are overlapping and its not going into onAudioFocusChange() 
Code for the same:

```
public class sampleMediaPlayer extends Activity implements AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener, OnClickListener {
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
private String myURL; 
AudioManager audioManager;
Button buttonStart, buttonStop;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        buttonStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStart);
        buttonStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonStop);

        buttonStart.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener(this);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);


    }


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();


        Log.e("123", "Inside sampleMediaPlayer");



}
    @Override
        protected void onStop() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onStop();

        }



    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int focusChange) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        Log.e("123", "focusChange============>>>>"+focusChange);
         switch (focusChange) {
            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN:
                Log.e("123", "focusChange======AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN======>>>>"+focusChange);
                requestFocus();
                // resume playback
                //AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN (1) : audio focus, or a request of audio focus, of unknown duration.
                if (mediaPlayer == null)
                    initMediaPlayer();
                else if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) 
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                mediaPlayer.setVolume(1.0f, 1.0f);

                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT:
                //AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT (2) : temporary gain or request of audio focus, e.g. event notification
                Log.e("123", "focusChange=======AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT=====>>>>"+focusChange);

//                  requestFocus();
//                  if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) 
//                      mediaPlayer.start();

                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK:
                //AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK (3) : temporary request of audio focus, anticipated to last a short amount of time,
                //and where it is acceptable for other audio applications to keep playing after having lowered their output level, 
                //e.g. playback of driving directions where playback of music in the background is acceptable.
                Log.e("123", "focusChange=======AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN_TRANSIENT_MAY_DUCK=====>>>>"+focusChange);
//                  requestFocus();
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS:
                // Lost focus for an unbounded amount of time: stop playback and release media player
                // -1
                Log.e("123", "focusChange=====AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS=======>>>>"+focusChange);
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                    mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
                abandonFocus();
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT:
                Log.e("123", "focusChange======AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT======>>>>"+focusChange);
                // Lost focus for a short time, but we have to stop
                // playback. We don't release the media player because playback
                // is likely to resume
                //-2
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) 
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                abandonFocus();
                break;

            case AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK:
                Log.e("123", "focusChange======AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS_TRANSIENT_CAN_DUCK======>>>>"+focusChange);
                // Lost focus for a short time, but it's ok to keep playing
                // at an attenuated level
                //-3
                if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) 
                    mediaPlayer.setVolume(0.1f, 0.1f);
                break;
        }
    }



    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    private void initMediaPlayer() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(mediaPlayer==null)
            mediaPlayer =  new MediaPlayer();
        //mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.braincandy);

        try {
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                myURL = "http://202.191.185.2:10406/thathi_thathi.mp3";
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(myURL);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
            }




            int result = audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
            boolean flag    =   requestFocus();

            Log.e("123", "result===============>>>"+result);
            if (result != AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED && flag==true) {
                // could not get audio focus.
                Toast.makeText(this, "AudioFocus Request Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(result == AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED){
                Toast.makeText(this, "AudioFocus Request Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("123", "Illegal Argument Exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("123", "Security Ecxeption");
            e.printStackTrace();
        //}
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            Log.e("123", "IO Exception----------");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    //  setAudioManager();

        mediaPlayer.start();
        Log.e("123", "Media Player started");
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        switch (arg0.getId()) {
        case R.id.buttonStart:

          Log.d("123", "onClick: starting srvice");
//            startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
        //  afh.requestFocus();
          requestFocus();
          initMediaPlayer();


          break;
        case R.id.buttonStop:
          Log.d("123", "onClick: stopping srvice");
//            stopService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
          //afh.abandonFocus();
          if(mediaPlayer != null){
          mediaPlayer.stop();
          mediaPlayer.release();
          abandonFocus();
          }
          break;
        }

    }

    public boolean requestFocus() {
        return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==
                audioManager.requestAudioFocus(this, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,
            AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_GAIN);
    }

    public boolean abandonFocus() {
        return AudioManager.AUDIOFOCUS_REQUEST_GRANTED ==
                audioManager.abandonAudioFocus(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: 01-07 16:55:14.259: V/MediaPlayer(17563): back from callback
01-07 16:55:14.559: E/123(17563): focusChange============>>>>-1
01-07 16:55:14.559: E/123(17563): focusChange=====AUDIOFOCUS_LOSS=======>>>>-1  the code works fine may be some device issue.

Comment: i am using this on Motorola Defy with 2.3.4 OS